# How to share var/www from VMWare Fusion to Mac OSX Host

Tags: linux, debian, vmware-fusion

Using VMware I've created a Virtual Machine running Debian. I have this set up as a web server. It all works fine.

But, I need to share the `var/www` directory from within the VM with my host so I can work on the files on the web server.

I've installed VMWare Tools, and setup a shared folder. But I'm unsure on how to share the `var/www` directory.

My host is running OSX 10.9.5 and the VM is Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

I installed samba (smb) on my linux virtual machine (ubuntu) and connect to it fron Finder with Connect to server and smb://10.0.1.x

It works like apple file protocol (AFP) and is easy to setup.